# Console app create crystal report failed

Tags: crystal-reports

I create the console app to generate the crystal report in VS2015. It worked on my development machine, but failed on testing machine. The app generated a few different reports. Some reports are failed and some reports are created successfully. All reports have no sub report.
For testing, I also tried to run the console app on another web server in which the webpage runs the same reports without problem but I still get the error on the console app.
 The error are :

"connect: incorrect log on parameters "

"logon failed"

The OS in the testing machine is Windows Server 2012 R2 and installed SAP Crystal Report Runtime Engine for .NET Framework for 32 and 64 bit. Also there are dsn on program file and Program Files (x86) folder. The console app is build on 4.5.1 .NET Framework. The Target CPU of the console app is AnyCPU. Even checking "Prefer 32-bit" or unchecking "Prefer 32 bit" on compile tab it makes no difference.

I searched the web and still no clue to solve the issue. Would someone can help me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the suggestion from Don Williams at [Logon failed.Error in File .rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3492989)

Finally I update the datasource location as same as dsn location in testing machine. The error is gone.